# Notification Alert for messages in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have PHP simple script in which i add only news, i need a formula in which it will do the following 
1. for any news messages or news added within 12 hours from the previous one it will show it as news and it will ad new near that message

2. the information in this script will be added in to database (Mysql)

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What do you want to display on the script? How do you add the news? Give us some example of how it should look like running the script.

Comment: example :  i see lest 30 news but some new write before 1 day  so any  new add i want give massage  the same this image http://www.uaeinteract.com/images/new.gif

Comment: i need the code for this if you could provide me

Comment: please edit your post and add provide the code you are actually using

Comment: my time is datetime . how can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store timestamp (you can access timestamp via time() function) and store it in your news database. When news listing you will check this timestamp with operators.

like

if ($timestamp > time() - 86400) echo 'new';

Comment: my time is datetime . how can do that?

Comment: $timestamp = strtotime($datetime)

Answer (score 1):

You should store the news' timestamp. When you display your news you should check the difference between current time and saved timestamp. If this difference is less than a day you should display new.gif.

Comment: my time is datetime . how can do that?